# add output of a script to a number in lua

Tags: lua

I have a shell script in Linux which outputs 10.

I want to write a script in lua, which adds 5 to my output of shell script. How can I use output of my shell script?

This is what I have tried -

```
print(5 + tonumber(os.execute('./sample')))
```

This is the output -

```
10
lua: temp.lua:2: bad argument #2 to 'tonumber' (number expected, got string)
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'tonumber'
    temp.lua:2: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Etan Reisner said, os.execute is returning multiple values, however, the exit code is not the first return value. Therefore, you'll have to stuff the values into variables:

```
local ok, reason, exitcode = os.execute("./sample")
if ok and reason == "exit" then
    print(5 + exitcode)
else
    -- The process failed or was terminated by a signal
end
```

By the way, if you want to return the new value as exit code, you can do so using os.exit:

```
os.exit(5 + exitcode)
```

Edit: As you have clarified via a comment, you are looking to read the **output** (stdout) of the process, not its **return value**. In this case, io.popen is the function you need:

```
local file = io.popen("./sample")
local value = file:read("*a")
print(5 + tonumber(value))
```

Note, however, that io.popen is [not available on every plattform](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-io.popen)

Comment: I get 0 as exit code, one thing, why do I need exit code from my shell script? shell script only contains `echo 10`

Comment: See my edit; You'll need io.popen to start the process and get a handle to its stdout